# Spark: How do I save an RDD before unpersist it

Tags: caching, apache-spark, rdd, persist

I want to unpersist myRDD after the data is saved. I have the following code:

```
  val isDone = myRDD.saveAsTextFile("myOutput")
  if (isDone != null) {
     myRDD.unpersist()
  }
```

but the line:

```
isDone != null
```

keeps saying: **comparing values of types Unit and Null using `!=' will always yield true**

What should be the correct way to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
myRDD.saveAsTextFile("myOutput")
myRDD.unpersist()
```

The data will be saved before the `RDD` is unpersisted.

Note that the `saveAsTextFile` method returns `Unit`. This is a type that is returned by any method (procedure) which does not return anything useful, and there is only one instance, i.e. `()`. So nothing useful is achieved by testing on the value returned by `saveAsTextFile`. Also, `Unit` being a subtype of `AnyVal` can never be equal to `null`, that's why you're getting the particular error that you're seeing. The same thing happens for `Ints`:

```
def foo(x: Int) = x != null
```